# Install CodeLite on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, c++

I have CentOS 6.4 I want to install CodeLite.

Their website http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Download#toc5 says that you need to compile it (as they don't have a package for CentOS).

I did

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/codelite/codelitegit codelite
```

and I got bunch of files. However they suggest to

```
cd codelite/
./configure
make
[Become the superuser]
make install
```

but it doesn't work as there is no `configure` in the `codelite` directory..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in the changelog of the latest version:
 **"codelite is now built using CMake"**
This may solve your problem.

Have a look here for more information:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/codelite/files/Releases/codelite-5.1/

Comment: seems u r right. I found cmake list file.. however centos only have 2.6 cmake rpm package and the cmake needs 2.8.... I give up.

Comment: You could always build cmake from source?